# How to do a function do receive a token with pgjwt

Tags: postgresql, jwt, token

iam trying to set up a function to get a token by jwt. It is in Postgres 15 and I want a function with the rolename and the secret as input.
But I get an error. If I hardcode this into the function it works.

this is what I have done:

```
CREATE EXTENSION pgjwt;
```

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION api.sign_jwt(role_name text, secret_key text)
 RETURNS text
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
DECLARE
    payload jsonb;
    token text;
    exp_time timestamp with time zone;
BEGIN
    
    exp_time = NOW() + interval '5 minutes';
    
    
    payload = jsonb_build_object('role', role_name, 'exp', EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM exp_time));

    
    token = sign(payload::text, secret_key);

    RETURN token;

END;
$function$
;
```

```
SELECT api.sign_jwt('meisneRolle', 'dawdawdwadw@%*dwadwadwwa');
```

Error:

```
SQL-Fehler [42883]: ERROR: function sign(text, text) does not exist
  Hinweis: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
  Wobei: PL/pgSQL function api.sign_jwt(text,text) line 14 at assignment

Fehlerposition:
```

This is working:

```
select api.sign('{"role": "meisneRolle"}', 'dawdawdwadw@%*dwadwadwwa');
```

And hardcode this into the function is working too:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION api.sign_jwt(role_name text, secret_key text)
 RETURNS text
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
DECLARE
    payload jsonb;
    token text;
    exp_time timestamp with time zone;
BEGIN
    
    exp_time = NOW() + interval '5 minutes';
    
    
    payload = jsonb_build_object('role', role_name, 'exp', EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM exp_time));

    
    --token = sign(payload::text, secret_key);
   token= sign('{"role": "meisneRolle"}', 'dawdawdwadw@%*dwadwadwwa');

    RETURN token;

END;
$function$
;
```

What do I miss?

Comment: Looks like the problem in your function is that you cast to text payload variable and it has to be JSON data type, as appears in [usage of pgjwt](https://github.com/michelp/pgjwt#usage) "Create a token. The first argument must be valid json, the second argument any text:"